# How to show that the set of three primes whose sum is a fixed integer is an integral?

Tags: number-theory

Let $I_F = \int_0^1 F(\alpha)^3 e^{-\alpha n} d\alpha$, where $F(\alpha)=\sum_{p\leq n} e^{\alpha p}$, $n$ is an integer. It is said that $I_F$ is the number of $(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ such that $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are primes and $p_1+p_2+p_3=n$. How to prove this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want "sum" in the title instead of "some"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$F(\alpha)^3 =\sum_{p_1,p_2,p_3, \leq n} e^{\alpha(p_1+p_2+p_3)} = \sum_k \sum_{p_1+p_2+p_3 =k} e^{\alpha k},$$
and for $k \neq n$,
$$ \int_0^1 e^{\alpha k} e^{-\alpha n} d\alpha =0.$$
I not sure about your notation but I guess that $e^\alpha := \exp(2i\pi \alpha)$.